# Huge data is not order by in spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to make DB to TO-MAKE in spark.

Below some query make DB to TO-MAKE in small data.

But That's ordering not working in huge data.

When huge data, result is rnk : 2,3,1,4,5 ...

So, how to fix query?

DB

[image]

TO-MAKE

[image]

1.

```
WITH base(
  SELECT
    id,
    time,
    name,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time) rnk
  FROM DB
  DISTRIBUTE BY id
  SORT BY id, rnk
)

SELECT
  id,
  CONCAT_WS(',',COLLECT_LIST(time)) time,
  CONCAT_WS(',',COLLECT_LIST(name)) name,
  CONCAT_WS(',',COLLECT_LIST(rnk)) rnk
FROM base
GROUP BY id
```

2. 

```
WITH base(
  SELECT
    id,
    time,
    name,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time) rnk
  FROM DB
  DISTRIBUTE BY id
  SORT BY id, rnk
)

SELECT
  id,
  CONCAT_WS(',',COLLECT_LIST(time)) time,
  CONCAT_WS(',',COLLECT_LIST(name)) name,
  CONCAT_WS(',',COLLECT_LIST(rnk)) rnk
FROM base
GROUP BY id 
DISTRIBUTE BY id
SORT BY id, rnk
```

3. 

```
WITH base(
  SELECT
    id,
    time,
    name,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time) rnk
  FROM DB
  DISTRIBUTE BY id
  SORT BY id, rnk
)

SELECT
  id,
  CONCAT_WS(',',COLLECT_LIST(time)) time,
  CONCAT_WS(',',COLLECT_LIST(name)) name,
  CONCAT_WS(',',COLLECT_LIST(rnk)) rnk
FROM base
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY rnk
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `time` column?

Comment: @Nithish time datatype is timestamp!